# How to callback process status from a PHP script,Java program to the calling bash shell

Tags: java, php, linux, bash, callback

**In brief**
I have a PHP and a Java program, either one of which is invoked from my shell depending on a condition. Those two programs are basically two paths of a similar task - one path is taken for one file format and another one for the other. I want those two paths to return a status (success or failure), and then the shell to read the callback and perform some common logic accordingly.

**Description**
 This is a representation -

```
         |
         |
         \/
     Shell logic
         |
         |
   ______________
   |  check a   |
   |  condition |
   ______________
   |            |
  /\           / \
 /  \         /   \
 |Yes|        |No |
 \  /         \  /
  \/           \/
   |           |
   |           |
   \/          \/
run PHP      run Java 
script        program
   |            |
   |            |
   \/           \/
 callback   callback  
 status      status
   |           |
   \/          \/
 ------------------
 | Detect callback |
 | status in shell |
 -------------------
         |
         |
         \/
    Do something
```

I invoke those programs like this -

```
php $dbx_parser_script_path/cli_complete_dbx_parser.php input_dbx_file=$input_file package_root=$package_root
```

and

```
java -classpath $package_root/some/jar/file:$package_root/examples/MessagesAndAttachments/src/ Example $input_file $package_root
```

So, two things -

- How do I callback from PHP and Java programs.
- How do I read the callback in shell?

Please note that both the programs echo some messages while they run. So, some kind of reading the printed output cannot be a clean solution. If there is some proper way of reading return value of the executed program in shell and both these languages - Java and PHP, can return some value to the caller script, then that it what I am looking for.

Thanks

**Update**

Fixed but this strange thing with $?

```
//after php script execution command - my php script ends with exit(1)
temp=$?
echo "See "$?" "$temp 
echo "with ?"   
if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
    echo "success"$?
else
    echo "failure"$?
fi

echo "with temp"    
if [ $temp -eq 1 ]; then
    echo "success"$temp 
else
    echo "failure"$temp     
fi
```

The output is -

```
See 0 1
with ?
failure1
with temp
success1
```

Why does the value of `$?` get lost. Why do I need to store it in another variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your java program, you can return an exit status like this:

```
//return exit status of 1
System.exit(1);
```

Similarly, in PHP:

```
//exit with an error code of 1
exit(1);
```

In your shell script, you can check the exit status of the last command executed using `$?`

Example:

```
#run java command
java Main args

#the exit status of the previous command is in `$?`. So check it:
if [ $? -eq 1 ]
then
    # do something
fi
```

Comment: okay I never thought about `exit()`. Thanks, but there is one strange thing about the shell part of the code. Please check my question update

Comment: `$?` holds the return status of the **previous** command. If you run a command and then echo something, $? will have the return status of echo not of your command. That's why you need to store it.